# Problema com Chronometer

Tags: android

No código, há uma variável `running`, que indica se o cronômetro está rodando ou não:

```
boolean running = false;
```

E há um método `StartStopTimer`, que para ou inicia o cronômetro de acordo com a variável:

```
   public void startStopTimer(View v){
    Chronometer chr = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.chronometer);
    Button ahj = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    if(running == false){
        chr.start();
        running = true;
        ahj.setText("Stop Timer");
    }
    else if(running == true){
        chr.stop();
        ahj.setText("Start Timer");
        running = false;
    }

}
```

Só que, quando eu rodo o aplicativo, o cronômetro não começa do zero. Se a aplicação está rodando há 15 segundos, por exemplo, ele começa dos 15 segundos.
Como fazer pra ele começar do 0?

Propriedades do cronômetro:

```
 <Chronometer
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/chronometer"
    android:textSize="100dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/valor1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Grato desde já :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basta reiniciar a Variavel do contador
Por exemplo se a variavel se chamar:

```
tempo
```

tem que meter

```
else if(running == true){
    tempo = 0;
    chr.stop();
    ahj.setText("Start Timer");
    running = false;
}
```